# How to invoke test in remote machine using selenium JS Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to execute test in remote machine using Selenium Grid and Javascript (in Node Js) I am now able to connect to remote machine from js.

In Java,  we use RemoteWebDriver and give Node machine URL. there are plenty of examples in Google

how will we do the same from Javascript. can any one please provide me step by step procedure to Invoke Sample tests in Node Machine from Hub Machine.

Many thanks
Vijay Bhargav